# "Housing" vs "Hosting"

Tags: word-choice, differences

What's the difference between the words *housing* and *hosting*?

1. "I will **host** a friend at my home"
2. "I will **house** a friend at my home".

Comment: Today, these terms are contextual. For example, housing can mean a box or casing like a housing for the circuit board or panel.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictoinary? What did it tell you? [This is a good dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/)

Comment: I have an analogy for you.  People often say inappropriately (for example), "We make servicing our clients our number one priority," instead of "We make serving our clients our number one priority."  You SERVICE cars; you SERVE people.  Likewise, you HOUSE transients, boarders, strangers; you HOST friends, families, guests, visitors, or strangers to whom you are showing hospitality.

Answer (score 1):

"Housing" just means providing a house for. "Hosting" means providing a location and also other things such as hospitality, food, entertainment, or whatever else is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Housing is building or shelters in which people live.
Where Hosting is One who receives or entertains guests in a social or official capacity.

Answer (score 0):

We house occupants and host guests. Hosting is either transient or ethereal. Housing requires physicality of containment.

- The mainframe chassis **houses** a hyper-processor array and their supporting hardware.
- The hyper-processor **occupants**, in turn, are a **host** to a hyper-virtual operating system.
- The hyper-virtual operating system **hosts** hundreds of instances of various **guest** operating system.
- Each **guest** operating system is unique and different from other **guests**.
- The hyper-virtual operating system is itself **transient** with respect to the power switch. Whereas, the **guest** operating systems are **transient** to the software switches of the master operating system.

Hosting and guests seem ephemeral. Whereas, housing and occupants denotes a sense of permanence.

- We are **hosting** a **guest** this week, who is a friend, here for a job interview.
- If her job interview is successful, we might explore **housing** her as a **tenant**.
- Tokyo has been chosen to host the 2020 Summer Olympics. Thus begins their building frenzy for buildings to house the deluge of athletes, as well as hosting the unprecedented number of visitors to the country.

Comment: in general hosting is mainly used in program hosting and web hosting.
program hosting is run a event web hosting is upload & install the software in server